# Entity framework add member table to my own DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, dbcontext

I have been following the tutorial here -

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/create_the_data_access_layer

to build an ASP.NET web application.

What happens here is that

- there all the member tables are under the "DefaultConnection" and
- the user table is created under that connection.

However, all the other tables corresponding to the data layer are created in a separate database, called "wingtiptoys" and all the data related to the products of the toy store they happen to be making gets stored in tables there.

Because of this, I am finding it hard to exchange information between the tables in these two databases.

In an application of my own I'm working on, the tables actually have member information and I need to join those with the member table created by ASP.NET.

For that matter, I'm totally at a loss as to how the mechanism from the login page to the default users table works. I just find that there is a ASPNetUsers table in the Default database and it has the toy user information I used to login while testing my application but I couldn't find any place in the code for the login/register pages that tell them to store the user information in a table of that name.

In short, how to I create get the members table (the functionality for which ASP.NET provided by default) which is in the default DB to interact with the products and other tables which are in a separate DB created for the data layer of the application.

One option is to create a members table in the latter and ETL the data from the default DB to the members table some how. However, this seems inefficient.

Also, is there a default method to access the id of the currently logged in user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your first question: you will just have to utilize different instances of `DbContext` (`ApplicationDbContext`, and whatever you named the `DbContext` for "wingtiptoys") together.

For your second question: in the context of a Controller, the user's username can be found with `System.Web.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`. In a Model, you'll have to use `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`. Given the user's username, it should be trivial to find the UserId:

```
db.Users.Single(m => m.Username == User.Identity.Name).Id;
```